# How does a password manager give users access to their passwords in clear text

Tags: database, security, encryption, hash, passwords

As the title suggests, I am indeed working on a personal password manager. I have seen a large number of questions posted here with most answers being "Don't do it, use an existing solution that's proven like Bitwarden, Keepass, Dashlane, etc." and I understand the reasoning. If you're unsure of the mechanics that need to be put in place, the result won't be secure and it'll be a major security risk.

However, someone one day decided to create a password manager from scratch and eventually built a business from it so technically anyone can (with the right questions and skills). Anyway, I'm not trying to build a business but I am using this as a programming exercise (could have thought of something simpler in hindsight).

Here is what I "know":

- Never store passwords in clear text (Should be obvious to anyone)
- Use a master password to protect the entirety of the password database
- Don't use a hash without at least a salt (same input gives same hash)
- The password manager should NEVER have access to the clear text password (passwords should be encrypted on the client side)

For a basic visualisation, lets assume we are working with this database structure:

```
Username | Salt | Hashed_Password
---------------------------------
User_1   | 1SIO | FBVDVS156FSD615
User_2   | 5F54 | GDFG50684SD54DS
....
```

As mentioned, the `Hashed_Password` here is generated from the original password and the user's `Salt`.

What I would like to know, or at least understand:

- How would (or does) a password manager give users the ability to autofill forms online or even simpler, visualise their stored passwords ?
- I understand how to store passwords securely but the retrieval is what I'm struggling to get my head around

In my mind, anything that needs to display clear text passwords for the user (the password manager interface for example) should be done client-side and the password manager should never have access to the clear text password but the whole point of storing a hashed password is that hashing is irreversible (unless you plan on bruteforcing the whole thing)

Many other responses to this type of question involved encrypting with an asymmetric encryption (which I'm not against personally).

Thanks in advance for your answers !

Comment: Well yes, the passwords need to be encrypted, not hashed.  You mention a client so in a client/server model the encrypted passwords exist on the server and are only decrypted within the client once the user enters their key.  bitwarden is fully open source btw.

Comment: Somehow I feel there's a huge gap in security between encrypting and hashing.. I've checked Bitwarden and surprisingly, I got lost in their repo and am still searching for the section of code where they store and retrieve passwords for the user

Comment: Seems two different use cases are mixed. If passwords are stored only for authentication (validation), then indeed a slow salted hash is the best we currently have. Then the password can be only validated, but not recovered. In case of a psswd manager you will have to encrypt the passwords, with much higher risk revealing all the secrets when leaked. And consider where to manage the encryption key